# Derive shoulder position from head and hands (Virtual Reality)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry

The minimal set of positional data common to current VR headsets is the position and orientation of the headset and also of a controller held in each hand. Direction of travel is typically a choice between moving where the headset is looking (gaze) or the direction the offhand controller is facing (point).

More ideal I think would be to travel in the direction the player's torso is facing - being more intuitive/immersive than pointing while permitting the player to look around at the same time. To get the torso orientation I think I would need to derive the position of both shoulders from the position and orientation of each controller.

If I assume the player is standing upright and that wrists are not bent I think I can count on the following data-points; [scalene triangle between neck/spine, shoulder and elbow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPZiE.jpg)

**N(xyz)** The top of the spine (neck), derived from headset position and orientation.

**E(xyz)** The elbow, derived from the hand position and orientation (projected back a pre-calculated distance which is proportional to the player height).

**E-N** The distance measured between the elbow and neck/spine.

**S-N** A pre-calculated *horizontal* distance between the shoulder and neck/spine (proportional to player height).

**E-S** A pre-calculated length for the upper arm (proportional to player height).

The math is beyond me but it's clear S (shoulder) could ordinarily exist anywhere on a circle perpendicular to E-N but for the fact that its vertical component (z) is known. Can anybody tell me how I might go about finding the x/y for S such that I have its full 3D coordinate? If it's not already clear I don't have a lot of math so baby steps would be much appreciated. Ultimately I'd need to code this (to run every frame).

EXAMPLE VALUES

In-game metres, x/y are horizontal coordinates, z is vertical (from ground at 0).

N(xyz): -0.02,  0.12, 1.39

S(xyz): ?.??, ?.??, 1.39

E(xyz):  0.03, -0.30, 1.41

E-N: 0.42

S-N: 0.18

E-S: 0.30

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GU89.jpg)

Comment: Do you have all the five (numerical) values: $N(xyz), E(xyz)$, E-N, S-N and E-S? Please cite a numerical example if possible.

Comment: Yes, of course, captured some example values, thank you for looking.

Comment: What is the value of $z$ for $S(xyz)$?

Comment: Same as for N (1.39).

Answer (score 1):

Consider this specific example. You can immediately form the following two equations based on the length of $SE$ and $NS$:

$$(x-0.03)^2 + (y+0.30)^2 + (z-1.41)^2 = (0.30)^2$$

$$(x+0.02)^2 + (y-0.12)^2 + (z-1.39)^2 = (0.18)^2$$

Since $z = 1.39$, the above system of equations simplifies to

$$(x-0.03)^2 + (y+0.30)^2 = 0.0896$$

$$(x+0.02)^2 + (y-0.12)^2 = 0.0324$$

Solving, we get the following two solutions:

$(0.104428, -0.0100681)$ and $(-0.110414, -0.0356446)$

Most probably only one of the above solutions is acceptable in this case, right?

For the general case, I found a solution for the following system of equations:

$$(x-A)^2+ (y-B)^2 + (z-C)^2= G^2$$
$$(x-D)^2 + (y-E)^2 + (z-F)^2 = H^2$$
$$z = F$$
$$A \neq D, B \neq E$$

The lengthy solution follows. I'll check the solution once again.

$$x = \frac{A^3 - A^2 D - \sqrt{-(B - E)^2 (A^4 - 4 A^3 D + 2 A^2 B^2 - 4 A^2 B E + 2 A^2 C^2 - 4 A^2 C F + 6 A^2 D^2 + 2 A^2 E^2 + 2 A^2 F^2 - 2 A^2 G^2 - 2 A^2 H^2 - 4 A B^2 D + 8 A B D E - 4 A C^2 D + 8 A C D F - 4 A D^3 - 4 A D E^2 - 4 A D F^2 + 4 A D G^2 + 4 A D H^2 + B^4 - 4 B^3 E + 2 B^2 C^2 - 4 B^2 C F + 2 B^2 D^2 + 6 B^2 E^2 + 2 B^2 F^2 - 2 B^2 G^2 - 2 B^2 H^2 - 4 B C^2 E + 8 B C E F - 4 B D^2 E - 4 B E^3 - 4 B E F^2 + 4 B E G^2 + 4 B E H^2 + C^4 - 4 C^3 F + 2 C^2 D^2 + 2 C^2 E^2 + 6 C^2 F^2 - 2 C^2 G^2 + 2 C^2 H^2 - 4 C D^2 F - 4 C E^2 F - 4 C F^3 + 4 C F G^2 - 4 C F H^2 + D^4 + 2 D^2 E^2 + 2 D^2 F^2 - 2 D^2 G^2 - 2 D^2 H^2 + E^4 + 2 E^2 F^2 - 2 E^2 G^2 - 2 E^2 H^2 + F^4 - 2 F^2 G^2 + 2 F^2 H^2 + G^4 - 2 G^2 H^2 + H^4)} + A B^2 - 2 A B E + A C^2 - 2 A C F - A D^2 + A E^2 + A F^2 - A G^2 + A H^2 + B^2 D - 2 B D E - C^2 D + 2 C D F + D^3 + D E^2 - D F^2 + D G^2 - D H^2}{2 (A^2 - 2 A D + B^2 - 2 B E + D^2 + E^2)}$$

$$y = \frac{B^4 - 2 E B^3 + A^2 B^2 + C^2 B^2 + D^2 B^2 + F^2 B^2 - G^2 B^2 + H^2 B^2 - 2 A D B^2 - 2 C F B^2 + 2 E^3 B - 2 E F^2 B + 2 E G^2 B - 2 E H^2 B - 2 C^2 E B + 4 C E F B - E^4 - A^2 E^2 + C^2 E^2 - D^2 E^2 + 2 A D E^2 + E^2 F^2 - E^2 G^2 + E^2 H^2 - 2 C E^2 F + A \sqrt{-(B - E)^2 (A^4 - 4 D A^3 + 2 B^2 A^2 + 2 C^2 A^2 + 6 D^2 A^2 + 2 E^2 A^2 + 2 F^2 A^2 - 2 G^2 A^2 - 2 H^2 A^2 - 4 B E A^2 - 4 C F A^2 - 4 D^3 A - 4 D E^2 A - 4 D F^2 A + 4 D G^2 A + 4 D H^2 A - 4 B^2 D A - 4 C^2 D A + 8 B D E A + 8 C D F A + B^4 + C^4 + D^4 + E^4 + F^4 + G^4 + H^4 - 4 B E^3 - 4 C F^3 + 2 B^2 C^2 + 2 B^2 D^2 + 2 C^2 D^2 + 6 B^2 E^2 + 2 C^2 E^2 + 2 D^2 E^2 + 2 B^2 F^2 + 6 C^2 F^2 + 2 D^2 F^2 + 2 E^2 F^2 - 4 B E F^2 - 2 B^2 G^2 - 2 C^2 G^2 - 2 D^2 G^2 - 2 E^2 G^2 - 2 F^2 G^2 + 4 B E G^2 + 4 C F G^2 - 2 B^2 H^2 + 2 C^2 H^2 - 2 D^2 H^2 - 2 E^2 H^2 + 2 F^2 H^2 - 2 G^2 H^2 + 4 B E H^2 - 4 C F H^2 - 4 B^3 E - 4 B C^2 E - 4 B D^2 E - 4 C^3 F - 4 C D^2 F - 4 C E^2 F - 4 B^2 C F + 8 B C E F)} - D \sqrt{-(B - E)^2 (A^4 - 4 D A^3 + 2 B^2 A^2 + 2 C^2 A^2 + 6 D^2 A^2 + 2 E^2 A^2 + 2 F^2 A^2 - 2 G^2 A^2 - 2 H^2 A^2 - 4 B E A^2 - 4 C F A^2 - 4 D^3 A - 4 D E^2 A - 4 D F^2 A + 4 D G^2 A + 4 D H^2 A - 4 B^2 D A - 4 C^2 D A + 8 B D E A + 8 C D F A + B^4 + C^4 + D^4 + E^4 + F^4 + G^4 + H^4 - 4 B E^3 - 4 C F^3 + 2 B^2 C^2 + 2 B^2 D^2 + 2 C^2 D^2 + 6 B^2 E^2 + 2 C^2 E^2 + 2 D^2 E^2 + 2 B^2 F^2 + 6 C^2 F^2 + 2 D^2 F^2 + 2 E^2 F^2 - 4 B E F^2 - 2 B^2 G^2 - 2 C^2 G^2 - 2 D^2 G^2 - 2 E^2 G^2 - 2 F^2 G^2 + 4 B E G^2 + 4 C F G^2 - 2 B^2 H^2 + 2 C^2 H^2 - 2 D^2 H^2 - 2 E^2 H^2 + 2 F^2 H^2 - 2 G^2 H^2 + 4 B E H^2 - 4 C F H^2 - 4 B^3 E - 4 B C^2 E - 4 B D^2 E - 4 C^3 F - 4 C D^2 F - 4 C E^2 F - 4 B^2 C F + 8 B C E F)}}{2 (B - E) (A^2 - 2 D A + B^2 + D^2 + E^2 - 2 B E)}$$

$$z = F$$

and

$$x = \frac{A^3 - A^2 D + \sqrt{-(B - E)^2 (A^4 - 4 A^3 D + 2 A^2 B^2 - 4 A^2 B E + 2 A^2 C^2 - 4 A^2 C F + 6 A^2 D^2 + 2 A^2 E^2 + 2 A^2 F^2 - 2 A^2 G^2 - 2 A^2 H^2 - 4 A B^2 D + 8 A B D E - 4 A C^2 D + 8 A C D F - 4 A D^3 - 4 A D E^2 - 4 A D F^2 + 4 A D G^2 + 4 A D H^2 + B^4 - 4 B^3 E + 2 B^2 C^2 - 4 B^2 C F + 2 B^2 D^2 + 6 B^2 E^2 + 2 B^2 F^2 - 2 B^2 G^2 - 2 B^2 H^2 - 4 B C^2 E + 8 B C E F - 4 B D^2 E - 4 B E^3 - 4 B E F^2 + 4 B E G^2 + 4 B E H^2 + C^4 - 4 C^3 F + 2 C^2 D^2 + 2 C^2 E^2 + 6 C^2 F^2 - 2 C^2 G^2 + 2 C^2 H^2 - 4 C D^2 F - 4 C E^2 F - 4 C F^3 + 4 C F G^2 - 4 C F H^2 + D^4 + 2 D^2 E^2 + 2 D^2 F^2 - 2 D^2 G^2 - 2 D^2 H^2 + E^4 + 2 E^2 F^2 - 2 E^2 G^2 - 2 E^2 H^2 + F^4 - 2 F^2 G^2 + 2 F^2 H^2 + G^4 - 2 G^2 H^2 + H^4)} + A B^2 - 2 A B E + A C^2 - 2 A C F - A D^2 + A E^2 + A F^2 - A G^2 + A H^2 + B^2 D - 2 B D E - C^2 D + 2 C D F + D^3 + D E^2 - D F^2 + D G^2 - D H^2}{2 (A^2 - 2 A D + B^2 - 2 B E + D^2 + E^2)}$$

$$y = \frac{B^4 - 2 E B^3 + A^2 B^2 + C^2 B^2 + D^2 B^2 + F^2 B^2 - G^2 B^2 + H^2 B^2 - 2 A D B^2 - 2 C F B^2 + 2 E^3 B - 2 E F^2 B + 2 E G^2 B - 2 E H^2 B - 2 C^2 E B + 4 C E F B - E^4 - A^2 E^2 + C^2 E^2 - D^2 E^2 + 2 A D E^2 + E^2 F^2 - E^2 G^2 + E^2 H^2 - 2 C E^2 F - A \sqrt{(-(B - E)^2 (A^4 - 4 D A^3 + 2 B^2 A^2 + 2 C^2 A^2 + 6 D^2 A^2 + 2 E^2 A^2 + 2 F^2 A^2 - 2 G^2 A^2 - 2 H^2 A^2 - 4 B E A^2 - 4 C F A^2 - 4 D^3 A - 4 D E^2 A - 4 D F^2 A + 4 D G^2 A + 4 D H^2 A - 4 B^2 D A - 4 C^2 D A + 8 B D E A + 8 C D F A + B^4 + C^4 + D^4 + E^4 + F^4 + G^4 + H^4 - 4 B E^3 - 4 C F^3 + 2 B^2 C^2 + 2 B^2 D^2 + 2 C^2 D^2 + 6 B^2 E^2 + 2 C^2 E^2 + 2 D^2 E^2 + 2 B^2 F^2 + 6 C^2 F^2 + 2 D^2 F^2 + 2 E^2 F^2 - 4 B E F^2 - 2 B^2 G^2 - 2 C^2 G^2 - 2 D^2 G^2 - 2 E^2 G^2 - 2 F^2 G^2 + 4 B E G^2 + 4 C F G^2 - 2 B^2 H^2 + 2 C^2 H^2 - 2 D^2 H^2 - 2 E^2 H^2 + 2 F^2 H^2 - 2 G^2 H^2 + 4 B E H^2 - 4 C F H^2 - 4 B^3 E - 4 B C^2 E - 4 B D^2 E - 4 C^3 F - 4 C D^2 F - 4 C E^2 F - 4 B^2 C F + 8 B C E F)} + D \sqrt{-(B - E)^2 (A^4 - 4 D A^3 + 2 B^2 A^2 + 2 C^2 A^2 + 6 D^2 A^2 + 2 E^2 A^2 + 2 F^2 A^2 - 2 G^2 A^2 - 2 H^2 A^2 - 4 B E A^2 - 4 C F A^2 - 4 D^3 A - 4 D E^2 A - 4 D F^2 A + 4 D G^2 A + 4 D H^2 A - 4 B^2 D A - 4 C^2 D A + 8 B D E A + 8 C D F A + B^4 + C^4 + D^4 + E^4 + F^4 + G^4 + H^4 - 4 B E^3 - 4 C F^3 + 2 B^2 C^2 + 2 B^2 D^2 + 2 C^2 D^2 + 6 B^2 E^2 + 2 C^2 E^2 + 2 D^2 E^2 + 2 B^2 F^2 + 6 C^2 F^2 + 2 D^2 F^2 + 2 E^2 F^2 - 4 B E F^2 - 2 B^2 G^2 - 2 C^2 G^2 - 2 D^2 G^2 - 2 E^2 G^2 - 2 F^2 G^2 + 4 B E G^2 + 4 C F G^2 - 2 B^2 H^2 + 2 C^2 H^2 - 2 D^2 H^2 - 2 E^2 H^2 + 2 F^2 H^2 - 2 G^2 H^2 + 4 B E H^2 - 4 C F H^2 - 4 B^3 E - 4 B C^2 E - 4 B D^2 E - 4 C^3 F - 4 C D^2 F - 4 C E^2 F - 4 B^2 C F + 8 B C E F)}}{2 (B - E) (A^2 - 2 D A + B^2 + D^2 + E^2 - 2 B E)}$$

$$z = F$$

Comment: I'm afraid I can't think of any way to simplify the inputs (beyond Sz==Nz). The lengths which are a proportion of player height may not change often but still need to be variable (and updated as/when a new maximum height is recorded). Interested in trying any generalised solution however complex as this is the only way I can test the approach (possibly an optimization might be revealed by the implementation). Very much appreciate the time you've given to this, thanks!

Comment: Is there a way I might project E(xyz) on to the Z plane? Wondering if this might then yield a simple rotation (by the new angle n, +ve on the right, -ve on the left) to get a vector toward S.

Comment: I guess projection would just be a case of adopting the Nz value and then using the right-triangle rule to get a new length for ES and EN. Thinking out loud, probably naïve but will give it a  go.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in replying. Wow! That is a lot of math - you've gone Full-Algebra! Very much appreciate your doing this, not quite sure I know how to implement it but I'm extremely tempted to try (if only as a proof) - just might take a while.